# roots of the equation $(abc^2)x^2+3a^2 cx+b^2cx-6a^2-ab+2b^2=0$ are rational

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$a,b,c$ are non zero , unequal rational numbers then prove that roots of the equation $$(abc^2)x^2+3a^2 cx+b^2cx-6a^2-ab+2b^2=0$$ are rational

quadratic eqn. in standard form $(abc^2)x^2+(3a^2c+b^2c)x-(6a^2+ab-2b^2) = 0$

$\displaystyle D=(3a^2c+b^2c)^2+4(abc^2)(6a^2+ab-2b^2) = 9a^4c^2+b^4c^2+6a^2b^2c^2+24a^3bc^2+4a^2b^2c^2-8ab^3c^2$

could some help me with this

Comment: The polynomial can be factored as $(b c x + 3a + 2 b)(a c x -2a+b)$

Comment: @Lozenges would u explain me in detail

Comment: $a b c^2 x^2+\left(3a^2c + b^2c\right)x+\left(-6a^2-a b +2b^2\right)=(b c x + 3a + 2 b)(a c x -2a+b)=0$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$B=3a^2c+b^2c=c(3a^2+b^2)$$

$$-C=6a^2+ab-2b^2=6a^2+4ab-3ab-2b^2=2a(3a+2b)-b(3a+2b)=(3a+2b)(2a-b)$$

$$A=abc^2$$

Break $$C\cdot A=(3a+2b)ac\cdot bc(2a-b)$$  as $$(3a+2b)ac-bc(2a-b)=B$$